# Multiple files are not getting copied to local directory in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using below code to save image data into local directory from Uris obtained through pick intent.

```
    private fun sendImages(uriString: String, messageBody: String, uriList: ArrayList<Uri>) {

    val pathList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val fileNameList = mutableListOf<String>()
    var fieSize = 0
    var multiSize = 0

    if(uriList.isEmpty() && uriString.isNotEmpty())
        uriList.add(Uri.parse(uriString))

        val localId: String = "localId"

        for(i in 0 until uriList.size) {
          val uri  = uriList[i]
          val path = FileUtils.getPath(application, uri)!!
          val fullName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
          val  name = "some function call that returns unique name for file"

          val file = File(requireActivity().applicationContext.filesDir, localId + name)
          file.createNewFile()
         
          var bitmapdata: ByteArray? = null
          var inputStream: InputStream? = null

            try {
                val ei = ExifInterface(path)
                val orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)
                var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
                bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(requireActivity().applicationContext.contentResolver, uri))
                }
                else MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireActivity().applicationContext.contentResolver, uri)
                val newBitmap = FunctionUtil.rotateImage(bitmap, orientation)
                bitmapdata = FileUtils.getCompressedBitmapForUpload(newBitmap!!)
                FunctionUtil.recycleBitmap(newBitmap)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
               return
            }
        }

        requireActivity().applicationContext.openFileOutput(file.name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
            it.write(bitmapdata)
        }


        val localPath = FunctionUtil.getMediaStorePath(requireActivity().application)

        val completePath = requireActivity().application.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)!!

       var  outFile =File(localPath+"/"+file.name)
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(file,outFile)
        Logger.log("PATH ${ outFile.absolutePath}  ${ outFile.path}")
        pathList.add(outFile.absolutePath)
        fileNameList.add(file.name)
        
     //... Do something with this data
    }
   }
```

**In the same code, if single file is copied to local directory, it is getting saved & i am able to send it . But whenever i try to save multiple files, the files are becoming empty when i try to send them.**

I am not able to find what issue is there. Please help

Comment: Get rid of `FileUtils.getPath()`. Use the `Uri` and `ContentResolver` `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` that you can use for copying the content.

Comment: @CommonsWare its working fine when copying single file. But when copying multiple  files its only copying last image in list. For storage we are using application scope.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare Same result with `ContentResolver` `openInputStream()`. When I am trying to access file gave me error  `Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 0):

Some Android phones will encounter such a problem :
the file does exist, but the 'fd' returned by the 'c++ open()' method is -1, and the 'strerror' showing 'No such file or directory".

The phones I have come across are as follows:

> vivo
> V2055A V2073A V2241A
> huawei
> GIA-AN00 JLH-AN00 CMA-AN00 HPB-AN00 NTN-AN20 CMA-AN40
> oppo
> LE2110

---

In the source code of the Android System, a similar phenomenon can also be found :

[image]

> The above is a comment added in 2017, and only the common 'bmp' and 'ico' formats are written.
> In face, this problem also occurs with pictures in 'heif/heic' format.

---

Finally,
Using 'FileInputStream' will be ok.